# react button onClick redirect page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am working on a web application using React and bootstrap. When it comes to applying button onClick, I'm having a hard time to have page being redirect to another. If after a href, I cannot go the another page.

So would you please tell me is there any need for using react-navigation or other to navigate the page using Button onClick ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Card, CardBody, CardGroup, Col, Container, Input, InputGroup, InputGroupAddon, InputGroupText, Row, NavLink  } from 'reactstrap';
 
class LoginLayout extends Component {
 
  render() {
    return (
 <div className="app flex-row align-items-center">
        <Container>
     ...
                    <Row>
                      <Col xs="6">                      
                        <Button color="primary" className="px-4">
                            Login
                         </Button>
                      </Col>
                      <Col xs="6" className="text-right">
                        <Button color="link" className="px-0">Forgot password?</Button>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
               ...
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Don't use a button as a link. Instead, use a link styled as a button.

```
<Link to="/signup" className="btn btn-primary">Sign up</Link>
```

Comment: I got an error not sure if that is related to it, ```link is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.```

Comment: That is not the question though.

Answer (score 201):

**update**:

**React Router v6**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
function LoginLayout() {
  
  let navigate = useNavigate(); 
  const routeChange = () =>{ 
    let path = `newPath`; 
    navigate(path);
  }
  
  return (
     <div className="app flex-row align-items-center">
      <Container>
      ...          
          <Button color="primary" className="px-4"
            onClick={routeChange}
              >
              Login
            </Button>
      ...
       </Container>
    </div>
  );
}}
```

**React Router v5 with hooks:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
function LoginLayout() {
  
  const history = useHistory();
  
  const routeChange = () =>{ 
    let path = `newPath`; 
    history.push(path);
  }

  return (
      <div className="app flex-row align-items-center">
        <Container>
          ...
          <Row>
            <Col xs="6">                      
              <Button color="primary" className="px-4"
                onClick={routeChange}
                  >
                  Login
                </Button>
            </Col>
            <Col xs="6" className="text-right">
              <Button color="link" className="px-0">Forgot password?</Button>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          ...
        </Container>
      </div>
  );
}
export default LoginLayout;
```

**with React Router v5:**

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button, Card, CardBody, CardGroup, Col, Container, Input, InputGroup, InputGroupAddon, InputGroupText, Row, NavLink  } from 'reactstrap';
    
class LoginLayout extends Component {
  
  routeChange=()=> {
    let path = `newPath`;
    let history = useHistory();
    history.push(path);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app flex-row align-items-center">
        <Container>
          ...
          <Row>
            <Col xs="6">                      
              <Button color="primary" className="px-4"
                onClick={this.routeChange}
                  >
                  Login
                </Button>
            </Col>
            <Col xs="6" className="text-right">
              <Button color="link" className="px-0">Forgot password?</Button>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          ...
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginLayout;
```

with React Router v4:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button, Card, CardBody, CardGroup, Col, Container, Input, InputGroup, InputGroupAddon, InputGroupText, Row, NavLink  } from 'reactstrap';
    
class LoginLayout extends Component {
  constuctor() {
    this.routeChange = this.routeChange.bind(this);
  }

  routeChange() {
    let path = `newPath`;
    this.props.history.push(path);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app flex-row align-items-center">
        <Container>
          ...
          <Row>
            <Col xs="6">                      
              <Button color="primary" className="px-4"
                onClick={this.routeChange}
                  >
                  Login
                </Button>
            </Col>
            <Col xs="6" className="text-right">
              <Button color="link" className="px-0">Forgot password?</Button>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          ...
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(LoginLayout);
```

Comment: After using above code, I'm still on the same page. Do I need to make any extra work other than this?

Comment: i suppose no.. did you wrap your component with `withRouter` ?

Comment: I have wrapped my component with `withRouter`. It works perfectly if I use single resource e.g. it works for the route `/MyProfile`. But that didn't work when I use `/MyProfile/edit`. How can I redirect to nested resource?

Comment: can you add it sandbox and provide me the link so that i can better resolve your issue

Comment: Can't do that in v5.1.2 with hooks. `React Hook "useHistory" is called in function "routeChange" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function.` Edit: Move `const history = useHistory()` outside of the handler if you face this issue.

Comment: same error  Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." when using  React Router v5

Comment: Not sure if this is useful, but if you're using or planning to use React router v6, you can't use `useHistory` anymore. They have replaced it with `useNavigate`.
`const navigate = useNavigate(); navigate('../edit')`
This will move from /some/path/profile to /some/path/edit

Answer (score 40):

React Router v5.1.2:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
const App = () => {
   const history = useHistory()
   <i className="icon list arrow left"
      onClick={() => {
        history.goBack()
   }}></i>
}
```

Comment: I failed already on the line 'const history = useHistory()' because of 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined'. Did you use anything of the react-router-dom in your index.js?

Answer (score 38):

This can be done very simply, you don't need to use a different function or library for it.

```
onClick={event =>  window.location.href='/your-href'}
```

Comment: Caution: This will reload the page.

Comment: @JamesPoulose exactly! Whats the recommended way of doing this without reloading whole page? I'm talking about routing onClick. For example when I'm clicking on details icon. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is bit slow, if compared to useHistory hook for functional component. Reloading might be reason

Answer (score 20):

I was trying to find a way with Redirect but failed. Redirecting onClick is simpler than we think. Just place the following basic JavaScript within your onClick function, no monkey business:

```
window.location.href="pagelink"
```

Comment: Caution: This will reload the page.

Comment: ye this defies the purpose of using react to make a single page application, will make all your react code to be resent etc etc (things like history will probably be reset)

Answer (score 12):

First, import it:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Then, in function or class:

```
const history = useHistory();
```

Finally, you put it in the `onClick` function:

```
<Button onClick={()=> history.push("/mypage")}>Click me!</Button>
```

Answer (score 8):

A very simple way to do this is by the following:

```
onClick={this.fun.bind(this)}
```

and for the function:

```
fun() {
  this.props.history.push("/Home");
}
```

finlay you need to import withRouter:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and export it as:

```
export default withRouter (comp_name);
```

Answer (score 7):

`useHistory()` from `react-router-dom` can fix your problem

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
function NavigationDemo() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const navigateTo = () => history.push('/componentURL');//eg.history.push('/login');

  return (
   <div>
   <button onClick={navigateTo} type="button" />
   </div>
  );
}
export default NavigationDemo;
```

Answer (score 7):

If all above methods fails use something like this:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Redirect } from "react-router";
    
    export default class Reedirect extends Component {
        state = {
            redirect: false
        }
        redirectHandler = () => {
            this.setState({ redirect: true })
            this.renderRedirect();
        }
        renderRedirect = () => {
            if (this.state.redirect) {
                return <Redirect to='/' />
            }
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <>
                    <button onClick={this.redirectHandler}>click me</button>
                    {this.renderRedirect()}
                </>
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

### if you want to redirect to a route on a Click event.

Just do this

#### In Functional Component

```js
props.history.push('/link')
```

#### In Class Component

```js
this.props.history.push('/link')
```

Example:

```
<button onClick={()=>{props.history.push('/link')}} >Press</button>
```

#### Tested on:

react-router-dom: 5.2.0,

react: 16.12.0

Answer (score 5):

If you already created a class to define the properties of your Button (If you have a button class created already), and you want to call it in another class and link it to another page through a button you created in this new class, just import your "Button" (or the name of your button class) and use the code below:

```
import React , {useState} from 'react';
import {Button} from '../Button';

function Iworkforbutton() {
const [button] = useState(true);

return (
    <div className='button-class'>
        {button && <Button onClick={()=> window.location.href='/yourPath'}
            I am Button </Button>
    </div>
    )
}

export default Iworkforbutton
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
And just hyperlink instead of using a function.

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

<Button>
   <Link to="/yourRoute">Route Name</Link>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple click handler on the button, and setting `window.location.hash` will do the trick, assuming that your destination is also within the app.

You can listen to the `hashchange` event on `window`, parse the URL you get, call `this.setState()`, and you have your own simple router, **no library needed**.

```
class LoginLayout extends Component {
    constuctor() {
      this.handlePageChange = this.handlePageChange.bind(this);
      this.handleRouteChange = this.handleRouteChange.bind(this);
      this.state = { page_number: 0 }
    }

  handlePageChange() {
    window.location.hash = "#/my/target/url";
  }

  handleRouteChange(event) {
    const destination = event.newURL;
    // check the URL string, or whatever other condition, to determine
    // how to set internal state.
    if (some_condition) {
      this.setState({ page_number: 1 });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', this.handleRouteChange, false);
  }

  render() {
    // @TODO: check this.state.page_number and render the correct page.
    return (
      <div className="app flex-row align-items-center">
        <Container>
          ...
                <Row>
                  <Col xs="6">                      
                    <Button 
                       color="primary"
                       className="px-4"
                       onClick={this.handlePageChange}
                    >
                        Login
                     </Button>
                  </Col>
                  <Col xs="6" className="text-right">
                    <Button color="link" className="px-0">Forgot password </Button>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
           ...
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: using window.location is not preferable for anyone looking to maintain any form of SPA (single page application). You have changed the browser's url and wiped out any state, etc.

Comment: When you say "wiped out any state", what do you have in mind, specifically?  I am using `location.hash`, which won't cause a page reload.

Answer (score 1):

With React Router v5.1:

```
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Button} from 'reactstrap';
.....
.....
export class yourComponent extends Component {
    .....
    componentDidMount() { 
        let history = useHistory;
        .......
    }

    render() {
        return(
        .....
        .....
            <Button className="fooBarClass" onClick={() => history.back()}>Back</Button>

        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the trouble to route to a different view using navlink.

My implementation was as follows  and works perfectly;

```
<NavLink tag='li'>
  <div
    onClick={() =>
      this.props.history.push('/admin/my- settings')
    }
  >
    <DropdownItem className='nav-item'>
      Settings
    </DropdownItem>
  </div>
</NavLink>
```

Wrap it with a div, assign the onClick handler to the div. Use the history object to push a new view.

Answer (score -1):

This also seems to work well:

```
<Button color="primary" tag={Link} to={"/some-page"}>
```