# How can I load another web page by clicking a button in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I want to go `DetailAboutUs` page by clicking `AboutUs` button. How can I do it?

This is my code.

```
render(){
    var buttonStyle;
    return(
        <div>

           <button
               className="btn btn-default"
            style={buttonStyle}
               onClick={this.props.clickHandler(DetailAboutUs)}>About Us

           </button>

        </div>
    )
```

Comment: are you using react-router ?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50644976/react-button-onclick-redirect-page

Answer (score 0):

You can have **flag** in the components **state** which tracks the click event, something like `isButtonClicked = false`.

Say you would like to load a page by name **DetailAboutUs** which is a component.

The code would look something like this.

```
isButtonClickedHandler = () => {
   this.setState({isButtonClicked = true});
}

render(){
    var buttonStyle;
    var detailAboutUs = this.state.isButtonClicked == true ? <DetailAboutUs> 
                        </DetailAboutUs> : null;

    return(
        <div>

           <button
               className="btn btn-default"
                style={buttonStyle}
                 onClick={this.isButtonClickedHandler()}>About Us

           </button>
          {detailAboutUs} //This will load only after the button click//

        </div>
    )
```